# APACHE LDAP (authnz_ldap) auth not working, what is the correct syntax in my case?

Tags: apache-2.2, ldap

I'm running a docker container with apache to host a webapp, and I'm trying to integrate LDAP auth.

I think my issue is with the syntax, as I never had to do with LDAP, I'm not sure how to fix this.

the error I get from my logs is:

```
AH01626: authorization result of Require valid-user : denied (no authenticated user yet)
```

and I need to fix the syntax here:

```
<AuthnProviderAlias ldap demo>
  AuthLDAPBindDN xxxxxxx
  AuthLDAPBindPassword yyyyyy
  AuthLDAPURL zzzzzzz
</AuthnProviderAlias>
```

so how do I fill these fields?

I tried multiple combinations, I put the values into quotes `("")`, and without quotes.
In the `AuthLDAPURL` I tried to put the ldap url with and without `"ldap:xxx.xxx.xx.xx"` in front of the ip address.

But most importantly, I'm not sure I put the right info in those places,

First of all, I have these informations, I have a LDAP `user` and `password`,that is created just to allow queries on the `ldap_search`, then I have the `"OU=xxx,OU=yyy,DC=zzz,DC=qqq"` part as well
and finally I have my LDAP ip address.

With these informations I can correctly in PHP make a connection with LDAP and retrieve the user list, so these credential work correctly.

Now for the `AuthnProviderAlias` setup, where do I put what information?

For `AuthLDAPBindDN`, what is the correct value here? Do I need to put the login name I have from the search user? or do I put the `"OU=xxx,OU=yyy,DC=zzz,DC=qqq"` part here?

Then for `AuthLDAPBindPassword` it seems pretty straightforward, I insert the password for the search user

Finally for `AuthLDAPURL` if guess here I put the LDAP server address, but in what format?

I found online different syntaxes used here, like:

```
AuthLDAPURL "ldap://xx.yyy.z.zz:port/OU=xxx,OU=yyy,DC=zzz,DC=yyy?samaccountname"

AuthLDAPURL "ldap://xx.yyy.z.zz:port/OU=xxx,OU=yyy,DC=zzz,DC=yyy"

AuthLDAPURL "ldap://xx.yyy.z.zz:port"

AuthLDAPURL "xx.yyy.z.zz:port"
```

So who can help me with the syntax? In LDAP we use the `"samaccountname"` as login usually

Thank you
and all these variants with and without quotes